# Finding users who have not registered for certain slots

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, relational

Sorry if this is such a basic question, but I'm new to relational databases in general and I couldn't find any information when I was looking at queries. I'm using Microsoft Access, but I'd probably understand it in terms of SQL as well, if its easier for someone to explain.

So let's say I have this database of people who can sign up for certain events.

The first table (People) has records for  an id, which is the primary key, followed by their first and last name.

The second table (Events) has records for an event id (primary key), the name, and the number of spots available.

The third table (Slots) has records for the spot id (primary key), the event id, and the person id.

Now what I'm trying to do is find the people who haven't signed up for, let's say three events. I've managed to make it show the slots that people have signed up for that are NOT those three events, but I can't get it to show just the people who haven't signed up for any of those three events (including people who haven't signed up for anything). Do I need to make multiple queries in order to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your type of question suggests a `not exists` query:

```
select p.*
from people as p
where not exists (select 1
                  from slots as s inner join
                       events as e
                       on s.slot_id = e.id
                  where s.person_id = p.id and
                        e.name in ("event1", "event2", "event3")
                 );
```